# Fabric error 0 sub-policies were satisfied when running first-network byfn.sh up command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hello everyone I followed the hyperledger-fabric tutorials, and installed the fabric docker images and fabric-samples repository. When i running `byfn.sh` up command, it throws folloing errors.

```
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |  
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
2019-09-09 02:32:24.220 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

`error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied`

how could I fix this error? thanks

Comment: trying doing docker `volume prune` and `docker system prune` command delete fabric-samples and reinstall binaries and images and rerun `./byfn.sh up` command. when i was introuduced with this error, i did the above mentioned step and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying doing `docker volume prune` and `docker system prune -a` command delete fabric-samples and reinstall binaries and images and rerun `./byfn.sh up` command. when i was introuduced with this error, i did the above mentioned step and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert 'sleep 10s' after every command.